# Why can't javac compile class with finalize

Tags: java, finalize

I have read similar questions on the stackoverflow,but they answer what to do about it (compile it with `-Xlint:deprecation`) and not why the error occurs in the first place.I want to know why the error popped in the first place.

The Box Class

```
public class box{
int height;
int length;
int breadth;

public int volume(){
    return height*length*breadth;
}
box(int h,int l,int b){
    height = h;
    length = l;
    breadth = b;
}
protected void finalize(){
    System.out.println("Im dying!!");
}}
```

The Test Class

```
public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
    box a = new box(12,12,12);
    System.out.println("The volume is :"+ a.volume());
    a = null;
}}
```

The Error:

```
Note: ./box.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47762986/2970947

Comment: It is **not an error**. It is a `Note`, aka a warning, that you're using deprecated API and that your code may no longer work in the **next** release of Java, where that deprecated API may be removed entirely.

Comment: *"what to do about it"* Stop using finalize.

Comment: You were never encouraged to use `finalize`, Java never made any promises about calling it, so you're actually better of using some other approach

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch that was Really helpful.

Comment: @Andreas, thank you I was actually reading The complete reference and it does talk about finalize so I was just trying it out.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Alright thanks, Will look at the alternatives.

Comment: @MrakVladar Guess you're reading an out-dated guide.