# Why does string.Join(" ", new object[] { null, "a", null, "b"}) retruns string.Empty?

Tags: c#, string, object, join

I noticed that `string.Join(" ", new object[] { null, "a", null, "b"})` returns `string.Empty`

Notice that `string.Join(" ", new string[] { null, "a", null, "b"})` returns `a  b` (as I would expect)

Things get vicious when concatenating characters:
`string.Join(" ", new object[] { null, 'a', null, 'b'})` which also returns `string.Empty`

Edit: Even though the documentation says it (thanks to @elgonzo), is there a valid reason such exception was implemented in the framework ?

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/uM9SVp

Comment: Hack `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",(new object[] { null, "a", null, "b"}).Select(s=>s)));`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the behaviour seen is the expected one, as the documentation states.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Do you close other million questions which have answers in documentation as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8):

> **Notes to Callers**
>
> If the first element of values is `null,` the `Join(String, Object[])`
>   method does not concatenate the elements in values but instead returns
>   `Empty`. A number of workarounds for this issue are available. The
>   easiest is to assign a value of Empty to the first element of the
>   array, as the following example shows.

```
object[] values = { null, "Cobb", 4189, 11434, .366 };
if (values[0] == null) values[0] = String.Empty;
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|", values));
// The example displays the following output:
//      |Cobb|4189|11434|0.366
```

I suggest you read it up, pretty interesting.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What else to make of it? The reference has it exactly implemented the way the documentation states `if values.Length == 0 || values[0] == null) return String.Empty;`. It's exactly what the OP asked

Comment: This answer is fine :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The post literally starts with a link to the documentation. That's not plagiarism. That's saving people time to show exactly the information they are after without needing to scan a page that might in the future at some point even disappear rendering the awnser useless

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Question closure aside, it's massively inappropriate to label this as plagiarism. Bolkay linked to the source and did not pretend like they are the author. If anything, SO (and SE) **specifically disallows link-only answers** and expects the relevant information to be copied into the answer because links might break.

Comment: "This question does not appear to be about programming " Never change StackOverflow. lol, absurd mod'ing.

Comment: @Stuart That's the message that is shown when a question is closed with a custom message

Comment: @Flater You are thinking this question *should* be answered, it should not. A comment with a message to the documentation along with a VTC was good enough, just as we do with typos

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: You're dodging the topic. I specifically started off with _"Question closure aside"_ and replied to your accusation of plagiarism. If question closure is warranted (which I find debatable but am willing to give you the benefit of the doubt there), that is no reason to wantonly accuse people of plagiarism. If anything, bolkay complied with the SO requirement to avoid link-only answers.

Comment: @Flater I chose the wrong word, sorry for English not being my first language :)

Comment: I think this is an interesting question why they chose this behaviour. Lookat referencesource they explicitly check the first item is null, and if so return string.Empty then append the rest of the  items in the array to the stringbuilder starting the loop at 1. It seems an odd decision choice!

Comment: @Stuart: To be fair, "why did ...?" is _usually_ an open-ended question that mostly invites interpretations and opinions. That being said, an answer with justified claims (evidence, documentation, or an "word of god" answer by a .Net designer) would be interesting and valid, but it's going to also open the door to many unwanted opinion pieces.

Comment: Might be a good idea to move this conversation to a chat room.

Comment: @Flater Re _"To be fair..."_: What you describe is _exactly_ happened the other day with [a "Why?.." question about Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56139760/2985643). I commented that the question was opinion based unless the poster was _"incredibly lucky and received an answer from the person who was responsible for deciding to deprecate finalize()"_, and lo and behold the person who was actually responsible gave a great answer to the question! The question also attracted a lousy answer, as you predicted.