# Getting the following err when compiling " Elevator.java uses or overrides a deprecated API"

Tags: java

I keep getting the following error when compiling the following code and can't find the source   "Elevator.java uses or overrides a deprecated API" "Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details". I believe it is because I am using an outdated input but can't for the life of me find where. Im sure it is obvious. Can anyone nudge me in the correct direction?
Thank you in advance

````
    private final int floors; // floors cannot be changes once set
    private int currentFloor;


    public Elevator(int floors) {
        this.floors = floors;
        currentFloor = 1;
    }

    // default constructor
    public Elevator() {
        floors = 5;
        currentFloor = 1;
    }

    public int getCurrentFloor() {
        return currentFloor;
    }

    public void up(int floor) {

        if (floor >= floors) {
            System.out.println("Floor entered #"+floor);
            System.out.println("Sorry - Invalid floor entered. Building has only " + floors + " floors.");
        } else if (floor < currentFloor) {
            System.out.println("Floor entered #"+floor);
            System.out.println("Sorry - Elevator currently at floor #" + floors);
        } else if (floor < 1) {
            System.out.println("Floor entered #"+floor);
            System.out.println("Sorry - Invalid floor number entered.");
        } else if (floor == currentFloor) {
            System.out.println("Elevator waiting at floor #" + floor);
        } else {
            for (int f = currentFloor; f <= floor; f++) {
                System.out.println("Elevator ascending... Current floor #" + f);
            }
            currentFloor = floor;
            System.out.println("Elevator currently at floor #"+currentFloor+". Please get inside.");
        }
    }

    public void down(int floor) {

        if (floor >= floors) {
            System.out.println("Floor entered #"+floor);
            System.out.println("Sorry - Invalid floor entered. Building has only " + floors + " floors.");
        } else if (floor > currentFloor) {

            System.out.println("Sorry - Elevator currently at floor #" + floors);
        } else if (floor < 1) {
            System.out.println("Floor entered #"+floor);
            System.out.println("Sorry - Invalid floor number entered.");
        } else if (floor == currentFloor) {
            System.out.println("Elevator waiting at floor #" + floor);
        } else {
            for (int f = currentFloor; f >= floor; f--) {
                System.out.println("Elevator descending... Current floor #" + f);
            }
            currentFloor = floor;
            System.out.println("Elevator currently at floor #"+currentFloor+". Please get inside.");
        }
    }

    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        currentFloor = 1;
        System.out.println("Elevator ending: elevator returned to the first floor.");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Elevator calgaryTower = new Elevator(20);
        System.out.println("calgaryTower.getCurrentFloor() = " + calgaryTower.getCurrentFloor());
        System.out.println("Pressed 6 ...");
        calgaryTower.up(6);
        System.out.println("Pressed 4 ...");
        calgaryTower.down(4);
        calgaryTower.up(4);
        calgaryTower.down(4);
        calgaryTower.up(30);
        calgaryTower.down(-9);

        calgaryTower = null; // variable set to null
        calgaryTower = new Elevator(); // variable set to a new object using default constructor
    }
}```
````

Comment: I wonder if the message "Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details" has any significance here? What would happen if you tried `javac MyClass.java -Xlint:deprecation` where MyClass is the name of your class file.

Comment: I believe you shouldn't use `finalize` anymore

Comment: finalize was deprecated. More detail is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139760/why-is-the-finalize-method-deprecated-in-java-9